# Understanding isinstance in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, isinstance

So basically I am having trouble understanding these 2 concepts. I've googled for 2 days and played around with those 2 to create some kind of a picture for myself but its still like I don't truly understand everything.
As much as I understand, isinstance is used as a base of a recursion if you need to work on a multilevel list and it returns true or false depending whether element? is of said type.
The thing is I know the definition of it but I simply can't make myself understand how it truly works in order to actually use it. I thought I'd put a sample code and perhaps some of you could explain thoroughly how the function works in every detail. Here it is:

```
def first_and_last(a):
    if not (isinstance(a,list)):
        return a
    elif a == []:
        return []
    else:
        return [first_and_last(a[0]), first_and_last(a[-1])]


print(first_and_last([[1, 2, 3, [3, 3, 4, 5]], 6, 7, 7]))
```

Basically that code is one shared by the teacher but the idea of the code is to return the first and the last element of every level of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Just map out the recursion here:

```
first_and_last([[1, 2, 3, [3, 3, 4, 5]], 6, 7, 7])
   a is a list and not equal to []
   first_and_last([1, 2, 3, [3, 3, 4, 5]])
       a is a list and not equal to []
       first_and_last(1)
           a is not a list
           return 1
       first_and_last([3, 3, 4, 5])
           a is a list and not equal to []
           first_and_last(3)
               a is not a list
               return 3
           first_and_last(5)
               a is not a list
               return 5
           return [3, 5]
       return [1, [3, 5]]
   first_and_last(7)
       a is not a list
       return 7
   return [[1, [3, 5]], 7]
```

So `isinstance()` is just used to find when the value passed in in that call is not a list, to terminate the recursive call tree.

Comment: Much love to you man! this problem had been bugging me for a while and now I finally understand how it works. I ended up watching your explanation and running through every command the function was supposed to make manually to see how it builds up the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `isinstance` is used to call `first_and_last` on and on as you can go deeper into the nested lists. Consider the first few calls: in the first call `a[0]` is the list: `[1,2,3[3,3,4,5]]`, but on the next call, `a[0]` is an integer `1`. You can't nest into an integer, and `isinstance` is the condition to detect that you've reached the level of "raw" list elements in "list of lists of lists... " hierarchical structure. Since you always access the first (`a[0]`) or the last (`a[-1]`) element of a list, the fact that it is not a list means that it's the thing you want to return (first or last element of the list, provided it's not a inner list).

The second condition guards against calling `a[0]` and `a[-1]` on an empty list. If it would happen that an empty list was contained in the input parameter this will just return it at once without attempting to process its non-existent elements.

Comment: And thanks to you as well! You explained it in works and the guy before you explained it as a code. Perfect answer for my problem!